# Как расшифровать ошибку в 1С, что в ней закодировано?

Tags: 1с

Есть такая ошибка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что означают цифры `45` и `137`?

Помимо цифр, хотелось бы узнать, что это за путь: `ВнешняяОбработка.Dropbox.Форма.Форма.Форма`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Помимо цифр, хотелось бы узнать, что это за путь:

Путь к модулю, в котором произошла ошибка. В данном случае возникла в модуле формы внешней обработки.

> Что означают цифры 45 и 137?

Это номер строки, где ошибка возникла. Для быстрого перехода по номеру строки в 1С можно использовать горячие клавиши "Ctrl + G".

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]